# Gradle duplicate entries : build failed

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gradle

I am running into this issue almost everytime when I add a new module to my app but this time I am not able to resolve it at all. I am sick and tired of not friendly messages and tools of gradle. Someone please help: If you need dependencies output too let me know - it's big :(

```
Error:
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:     com/google/appengine/tools/appstats/Inter
>   nalProtos$1.class

Here are 4 gradle files:

Top level gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

   }
}
```

App gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'hugo'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.1.1'
compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:0.+@aar'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.3.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')


compile project(path: ':commons')
}
```

Backend gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'

    compile project(path: ':commons')
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

Commons gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
}
```

Comment: change 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'  to  'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta3'. Hope it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed compile project(path: ':commons') and it all worked. But I had to put same POJO in both app and backened. Putting them in common screwed up gradle. May be there is better way to share classes across app and backend.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
       compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

It might help you.

Comment: Did not helped. Got this error:
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class

Answer (score 0):

you can try this under

android {

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

might help you